# Who attacks first in a battle of Readied Attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, initiative, reactions

This question is best illustrated in an abridged example:

> Combat has already begun and a goblin sees a Paladin on his noble steed. He readies an attack on this trigger: When the Paladin enters my range, I will attack him.
>
> The Paladin's turn begins, and he readies an attack as well - When the Goblin enters my range, I will attack him.
>
> The Paladin's mount then goes, rushing down towards the Goblin, Paladin on his back. He enter's the Goblin's range, and...

Who strikes first?

RAW, I couldn't find a definitive source that solved the matter - I wanted to say that because the Goblin had a higher initiative count, his reaction went first. However, the Paladin has quite impressive Dex, and argued that it should be a contest of Sleight of Hand, which also makes sense to me.

Initiative has a small section about resolving standard ties with initiative, but I feel it doesn't apply here after initiative has already been determined.

***Initiative***

> "...The GM can decide the order if the tie is between a monster and a player character. Optionally, the GM can have the tied characters and monsters each roll a d20 to determine the order, highest roll going first."

I am also aware of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/in-what-order-do-multiple-readied-actions-with-the-same-trigger-resolve), which provides an answer, but using 3.5 Edition Rules.

**Who goes first in a simultaneous reaction trigger when combat has already begun in 5th edition? Is there any clarification in the rules from 5th Edition sources?**

Comment: I know that you did edit it to try and separate it from the duplicate question, but the question duplicate issue is still pretty much the same.  For more information, including some information on things defined by 5e books, check out this answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131702/45619

Comment: Definitely, I appreciate the reclarification. I was looking for a Twitter/Sage Advice post and ultimately I got one. Thanks!